# From a class, how do you modify a string from the GUI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

From this class, I'd like to modify the "MONTHLY" and "ROI" strings from the GUI using a ComboBox? I've searched but couldn't find anything concrete.

Do you have any ideas?

```
using BasicProject.Model;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class BinanceApi
{

    public static async Task<List<UserRank>> GetLeaderboardRank(string tradeType)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient((HttpMessageHandler)new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseCookies = false
            }))
            {
                string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new
                {
                    tradeType = tradeType,
                    isShared = true,
                    isTrader = false,
                    periodType = "MONTHLY", // ALL, MONTHLY, WEEKLY, DAILY
                    statisticsType = "ROI" // ROI, PNL
                });

            }
            return userRanks;
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        BinanceApi.Log.Error((object) ex);
        return (List<UserRank>)null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define a public `event` in you class and `Invoke` it. Now you can let your form subscribe to this event.

Comment: Thank you for answering... do you have an example please as I don't see it at all

Comment: Visual Studio is an editor...are you having an issue with editing or code? Is this a wpf app, asp, maui or winforms?

Comment: I'm using winforms and it's a code problem

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Comment: Why are you casting to `(object)` in the call to those two methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add two comboBoxes to the Winforms designer, and then name them periodTypeComboBox and statisticsTypeComboBox in the attribute name of the comboBox.

[image]

[image]

Then edit the items in the comboBox as follows:

[image]

[image]

In this way, you can select the item in the comboBox after winforms is started.

Finally change the code in your api to:

```
public static async Task<List<UserRank>> GetLeaderboardRank(string tradeType, string periodTypeComboBox, string statisticsTypeComboBox)  //changed
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient((HttpMessageHandler)new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseCookies = false
        }))
        {
            string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new
            {
                tradeType = tradeType,
                isShared = true,
                isTrader = false,
                periodType = periodTypeComboBox, //changed
                statisticsType = statisticsTypeComboBox // changed
            });

        }
        return userRanks;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        BinanceApi.Log.Error((object)ex);
        return (List<UserRank>)null;
    }
}
```

When calling this method in Form, it can be written as:

```
GetLeaderboardRank("AnytradeType",periodTypeComboBox.Text , statisticsTypeComboBox.Text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I read your reply today... I tried as you described and found 2 errors:

The name 'periodTypeComboBox' does not exist in the current context.
The name 'statisticsTypeComboBox' does not exist in the current context.

PS: My API is in a class and not the constucteur

Comment: @QuickSilvain Hi, I updated my answer. If you have any questions I'd love to help you

Comment: Hi and thanks, yes I had renamed comboBox1 to periodTypeComboBox and comboBox2 to statisticsTypeComboBox but I get the 2 errors I quoted above

Comment: @QuickSilvain Hi, I updated my answer, sorry for not considering this is an api before